# How can I close a JFrame by click on a button?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I would like to have a button in my window such that if I click it (button) the window is closed.

I found out that I can close a window in the following way:

```
referenceToTheFrame.hide(); //hides the frame from view
refToTheFrame.dispose(); //disposes the frame from memory
```

But if I do this way, compiler complains:

```
Note: myProgram.java uses or overrides a deprecated API
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprication for details.
```

Do I do something unsafe?

Comment: You dont want the frame to simply close when you click the "x"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recommended way is to use:

```
referenceToTheFrame.setVisible(false)
```

The `hide` method is deprecated and should not longer be used. (Although internally `setVisible` will call `hide` or `show`)

Additionally if you want to dispose the frame, you have to call `dispose` manually. (In case you need the window-closed event for example) A call to `setDefaultCloseOperation` doesn't help you here, because it only affects the behavior after a click on the close button from the system menu.

See the [Swing documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html#windowevents) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

DR has the correct answer.  Regarding the compiler warnings:  [hide()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#hide()) is a deprecated call belonging to [Window](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html).  Don't ever use it, stick with setVisible().

Answer (score 2):

Use `dispose()` on the frame object.